# Why Magento Core team doesn't notify us when modifies duplicate customer email addresses in upgrade script?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, upgrade-script

I was monitoring SQL queries during upgrade from Magento 1.5 to Magento 1.9.2.1

I noticed that in upgrade-1.6.2.0.1-1.6.2.0.2.php of Customer module Magento Core team modifies all duplicate customer email addresses in order later to add unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE `customer_entity` ADD UNIQUE `UNQ_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID` (`email`,`website_id`)
```

Before upgrade script is executed we have:

```
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| entity_id | website_id |         email       |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
|   65477   |      1     | mailbox@example.com |
|   65478   |      1     | mailbox@example.com |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

After upgrade script is executed we have:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| entity_id | website_id |                  email              |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------+
|   65477   |      1     |                 mailbox@example.com |
|   65478   |      1     | (duplicate65478)mailbox@example.com |
+-----------+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

My question is: "**Is this operation safe enough and is there any possibility that active customers could not be able to login?**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking over the code referenced to remove the duplicates:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/upgrade-1.6.2.0.1-1.6.2.0.2.php

It's safe to assume that existing records would remain intact, especially since the values (emails) are being renamed and NOT deleted.

Also, the possibility of the renamed record being used instead is not possibly with the frontend email validation checks as well as the method `loadByEmail`

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php#L201